# masonary photoswipe plugin not working

Tags: wordpress, masonry, photoswipe

in my blog Masonary Potoswipe plugin suddenly stopped working properly, it was working fine when I installed it, now photoswipe functionality s working but gallery images are not organized in masonary grid. 
http://aletere.com/deepak-perwani-social-round-up-9/

I contacted the support team they said it is some JS error, but as I am very new to coding stuff I cant figure it out.
please help!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check console logs on chrome (Press F12).

There says `imagesLoaded` is not defined (you called the function but it's not defined anywhere) on line 49 and you have syntax error on line 86